# Credit department is asking me to email them a color copy of my US social security card - how unsafe is this?

Tags: network, email

I applied to take over a friends lease vehicle because they are moving to Europe, and received an email from the vehicle manufacturers lease department, asking that I submit a color copy of my U.S. Social Security Card.

[image: email requesting the card]

I called their customer service number and asked if they have a way for me to upload this directly to their server, but the answer to that question was "no". However they did tell me that I can fax it but they are still expecting to receive a color version of the card.

They also said that their email is secure but it is the transit that I am a bit concerned about.

So, unless I am able to find a local faxing service that has a color fax, the only option given by this car manufacturer is for me to email the copy of the card.

I wanted to get a better idea of the risks of emailing a scanned copy of a U.S. social security card. What are the risks with doing so?

Comment: it's actually probably safer than sending a plain-text version; anyone can turn a number into a card image anyway, but at least this way, its hard to detect via a regexp and pluck out of packets in-transit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything about this seems dodgy to me, but then again in the financial space a lot of stuff is outsourced so the quality controls may not be there.

I'd expect better from Mercedes to be honest-- I called the number and they only have office hours in CST (pretty standard for third-rate credit card companies, debt collectors and other low-tier banking services) so I'm guessing they too probably outsourced their financial services to a call center in St. Louis or Ohio somewhere.

If you're convinced it's legit, what I would do is scan and email the image in an encrypted archive. So all you're transmitting is an encrypted zip file-- **don't email them the password.** But make it something you can easily verbally communicate.

Then, you call them and you tell the CSR you just sent the document, and you need to have her record the password on your file. She'll make a note of it on your file and whatever underwriter is looking at this (should) know what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you do not include a color copy of your U.S. social security card in this matter. Even if they say that it is a secure transaction, it would be safer to assume that it is not. Email servers get compromised all the time. It would be incredibly risky.

One red flag in this email is them rushing you to send it: this is not typical, and sounds like a phishing attempt. The subject line ***URGENT ACTION REQUIRED*** and threatening an undesired action if you do not comply within a strict time frame is a sign of this.

In addition, I'm not sure what avenue you could take to even verify that is indeed Mercedes-Benz. I would locate a number independent of this email to phone Mercedes-Benz and ask about this kind of email. They should be able to accommodate your request based on security concerns. If they do not, like ISMSDEV said, its up to you whether or not take this risk if this is the only method they will allow.

Comment: Totally agree about it looking dodgy. The subject looks suspicious, and the email is addressed to Valued Customer (another indicator). My answer still stands by addressing the risks of sending the email, that said I wouldn't risk it at all in this instance.

Comment: I agree with not risking it all, that being said, it is OP's decision. Good catch on the addressee, them not calling him by name is suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got the right contact info (The listed 855 number isn't what's listed on the MBFS Website at https://www.mbfs.com/mbfsr/en/misc/contactUs.do) There's nothing particularly more risky about emailing a scanned copy of your SS card than simply a typed in version.

Social Security numbers are held by every employer big and small.  They're held by banks, financial institutions, credit card processors, etc.  In short, your SS# is likely already held by hundreds of entities across the country.

Sending your SS# through email isn't secure of course, and the email could be compromised, and possibly discovered by identity thieves.  The risks are unlikely in transit, and more likely at rest.

You have to weigh this additional attack vector with all the other attack vectors that ALREADY exist, and you take every day and have no control over.  It's unlikely that all the various systems holding your SS# are particularly secure.  You presumably are already taking these risks by being employed, applying for credit cards, applying for loans, having a bank account, having a 401k, etc.  Why is this event any different from those?

Don't let the illusion of having or not having "a security layer", or sprinkling some encryption here or there fool you into thinking these risks aren't largely the same.

Answer (score 0):

The risks are the same as when sending any personal information via email. The email can be sent over the internet in the clear, allowing eavesdroppers to take a copy. When it arrives at the end email server it can then be stored there or forwarded on to an unlimited amount of users.

You are right to be concerned. That said if this is the only method they are willing to accept you need to accept the risk or decide not to complete the transaction.